# How can I use Google Custom Search ad free?

Tags: google-custom-search

Having the custom search engine code installed in my site but I'm seeing ads in the search result.

[this is the link](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=008232271608633827563:x8qj9d4rvva)

Is it possible to hide ads?

Do I have to pay if I want an ad free version?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but this info is oddly difficult to find.

To sum up:

Google discontinued their paid option of ad-free custom search engine about in April of 2018. That was their quick and easy version, what is now referred to as the "Standard Search Element" version of the Custom Search Engine - free and full of ads.

So the only way to use custom search on your site now is by using their JSON API:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page for info on the different Custom Search offerings: 
 https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/9069107